# How to find all the elements with this attribute?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I want to find a  element who has a particular attribute given that we do not know the attribute's value. In the example, I want to find all the div elements who have data-id as an attribute.

```
soup.findAll('div',{'data-id'})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `dict` (instead of `set`) with key as attribute's name and value as `True`:

```
data = '''
    <div data-id="1">xxx</div>
'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

print( soup.find_all('div',{'data-id':True}) )
```

Prints:

```
[<div data-id="1">xxx</div>]
```

---

Or you can use CSS selector:

```
print( soup.select('div[data-id]') )
```

Prints:

```
[<div data-id="1">xxx</div>]
```